# xml with element and attribute together c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How can I create a class in c# to map the following xml:

```
<Items>
<Item Name="Title">Title goes here</Item>
<Item Name="Description">Description goes here</Item>
<Item Name="Gender">Gender goes here</Item>
<Items>
```

I have tried many different things, I know how to set the element name and attribute name separately but I need them together as per the example.
Please note that this should not be an array.

I should be able to navigate through like:
Items.Title = "title"

There is something important that needs to be added: the attributes Title, Description, Gender (plus about 10 attributes) are values that I am not passing. This should "belong" to the model (class). Hence why my example of accessing the object via Items.Title = "title" where Title is the property of the object that needs to receive the value.

Comment: How. I need an example

Comment: I am also expecting what attributes to use, xmlElement, xmlAttribute, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a utility that comes with Visual Studio called XSD.exe.

You access it via the Visual Studio Developer command prompt.

Use this utility to generate your class(es) from the XML. Issuing the following command will give you all the options:

`XSD /?`

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I did try this, however it creates the array that I dont want. Please see my edit in the question. the values of the attributes should be in the model, I will not be passing it to the object, I will actually find the property, say Title and then set the value.

Comment: Unfortunately then you will need to craft it yourself. One hint is to make a `Public` method to expose the array(s) as a list, eg : `ToList();` HTH

Comment: yeah, after spending hours trying a way around, I ended up with the arrays that I did not wanted. I thought I would be able to find something that would allow me to set the XmlElement attribute (Item) and what should be its parent (Items). Anyway, I will mark your answer as correct because it may be useful for others. thanks Jeremy